# Create mapping of different unique string values into unique integer values with specified range

Tags: java, string, random, unique

I am facing one issue in which I want to map list of string from one application to unique integer but with specified range (like 0 to 99999).

Example:

```
"Input_str_1" should (for example) mapped to 5423 each time
"Input_str_2" should (for example) mapped to 4829 each time
```

Here important consideration is that for same input string I should get same number from given range each time. My input string will not be more than 1,00,000. So I have specified this range.

I am unable to get starting pointer on how to approach this problem. If any of you can help me in this direction that will be grateful.

My both application are in java.

Comment: 1) Do the mappings need to be persistent?  2) If not, a simple Map<String,Integer> can hold the mappings, and use 'theMap.size()' as the next available number.  3) Stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service, you'll need to show us your attempt at solution.

Comment: Mapping don't needs to be persistent. Actually I was not looking for ready to use code that's why I ask for pointer on "How to approach this problem?"

Comment: To map a string onto a number use a hash function.

Comment: Try `theString.hashCode() % 100000`

Comment: Good hash function shall do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to produce a unique number, or simply a random-looking number? If the latter, any hash function will suffice. Otherwise, if there are N possible inputs, and all other inputs are invalid, look at perfect hash functions.